# What is the advantage of flash() over using render_template() args?

Tags: flask

Today I learned Flask's flash() method.
What I understood was, it tells template to show message once.
But it can also be done by render_template() method like below:

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if condition:
        error = "Some error messages to flash"
    else:
        error = None
    return render_template('index.html', error=error)
```

This makes flash() method look like an unnecessary duplicate.
What kind of advantages or difference in practice are there to use flash over this?

Comment: What if you wanted to `redirect(...)` instead of `render_template(...)`? How would you get the message to pop up on the redirected page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you issue a redirect to, say, `/profile`, how would you know if the user visited that page himself, or he's redirected as a result of an action (like after a login)?

`flash()` method saves the message to the user session, so that they don't get lost due to navigation.

You can't use `render_template(name, message="success")` in this case, because when you redirect the user, the browser doesn't care about the response, when it sees a `30x` response, it reads the `Location` header and loads that URL in a new request, so whatever context you've set, or whatever you render, is all discarded. That's why you need to `flash` messages to pass messages between two consequent requests.

Also, read the explanation in flask docs, it's quite clear.
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/flashing/